# Flutter: How to access property from it's state class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am designing a custom textfield

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {

   final String labelText;
   final TextEditingController textEditingController;

   String get text {
       // Expected compilation error: "Undefined name '_textEditingController'"
       return _textEditingController.text;
   }

    MyTextField({
        Key key,
        this.labelText,
        this.textEditingController,
        .....
        .....
      }) : super(key: key);
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
    TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();
       _textEditingController = widget.editingController ?? TextEditingController();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
            ....,
            ....,
          ),
       )
    }
}
```

I am getting a compilation error `Undefined name '_textEditingController'` and it is expected as `_textEditingController` is defined in different class.

Now my question is how I can access `_textEditingController` property there?

Hope from the above code snippets helps you to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want. Declare the Controller in the Widget, since you can still access Widget members from State. Just make sure to check if _textEdittingController has a value before using it in your getter.

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
    TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

   final String labelText;

   String get title {
       // Error area
       return _textEditingController.text;
   }

    MyTextField({
        Key key,
        this.labelText,
      }) : super(key: key);

   _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: widget._textEditingController,

          ),
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code snippets with initState. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be other way around. Not from state to widget, the data flow should be from widget to state. So declare the below code inside MyTextField widget.

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

Then you can access the _textEditingController from the state class like below:

```
widget._textEditingController
```

Comment: I need the opposite direction of data access. Please refer to the question.

Comment: there should have a very strong reason to alter the normal flow, may I know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use myTextField.text

Comment: btw there should be a createState() method overridden in your widget!

Comment: I got your point but with this MyTextField is complaining that "This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final"